# Phonegap ios Camera fails on device not simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, camera

I'm using Phonegap to make a little app for IOS and android that uses the camera of the device and then I upload it with Phonegap Build. The problem is that the camera plugin doesn't seem to work on a device, altho it works on a simulator ( opens up the photolibrary, so I know it works).
I use the following code:

`navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});`

The device doesn't even go to the onFail function, I believe it doesn't recognize getPicture as a function since it does recognize navigator.camera as an object.

I believe the problem lays somewhere in the config.xml file since if I delete the geolocation plugin ( that works ) it still uses that plugin for some reason.

Here are the things I've put in the xml:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
<gap: Camera ...> (forgot the syntax)
```

This might sound vage and I probably left out some important info, but any info you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Years late, but I this may help others in the future: I suspect that the problem here was that [Xcode simulator does not support audio and video input](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1) as of iOS 8.2, which was shortly before this question was asked.

> Though most of the functionality of devices can be simulated in Simulator, some hardware features must be tested directly on a device. The hardware features that are not simulated as of iOS 8.2 are:
>
> Motion support (accelerometer and gyroscope) are unsupported.
> Audio and video input (**camera** and microphone) are unsupported.