# Cordova, iOS Simulator and the Camera Plugin - Nothing Happens

Tags: ios, cordova

Hy!

I'm playing around with cordova a little bit and encountered a problem very early. I have a Cordova 6.4 Project with iOS as the Platform, XCode 8.2 installed and the Camera Plugin Installed.

ALSO it won't work using the actual device.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitName").click(function(){
    navigator.notification.alert(
        $("#inputName").val(),  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
    );
    navigator.camera.getPicture(myResponse, myResponse, {destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY})
  })
});

function alertDismissed(){
  // do something
}

function myResponse(answer){
  alert(answer);
}
```

While the notification is displayed, the photo library does not appear. Why? I'm not even asked if I want to allow the app to access the library.

I'm sure there is a very simple solution to my problem.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that your code is all right. I recommend to take a look an the installtion of the camera, can you just call camera alone?

Comment: Unfortunately the iOS Simulator can not simulate a camera. That's why i chose `Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY` as my source. I can however start the photolibrary app in the simulator. But nothing happens in the app. ADDITIONALLY, there is no console.log file in platforms/ios/cordova

Comment: The issue is `navigator.camera`, even though you telling the source to be the photo library, a simulator does not respond to `navigator.camera` as no camera is present. you need to test on a device.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, neither the camera, nor the photo library are launching on the device either.

Comment: Also, the confix.xml in the root of the project does not contain ANY <feature> tags. Is that correct? Could that be the problem? I added the plugins with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera` Or are there different config.xml files for different platforms? AND I just updated to Cordova 6.5 - nothing changed...

Comment: @NitricWare: Its been a while since I tested with simulator but are you sure that it can not run the photo library? In this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26760675/2401386) the sim works but not the device.

Comment: @Blauharley yes, independent from where I test the app (simulator or device) when i click the button, the notification alert appears and then when the library should appear, nothing happens.

Comment: I i also added a snippet that checks the geolocation. It works perfectly: iOS asks me if I want to allow it and then gives me the geolocation information. It's just the camera that does not work...

Comment: Okay, THAT's weird - Copy and paste this code into the exact same project works like a charm... https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/cordova-core-plugin-camera-short-code-example I'll investigate...

Comment: I have same issue but camera works fine just Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY just not working